# Force sprockets to compile asset during test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a custom sprockets engine and a test to go with it (rspec).  The spec does a visit of /assets/application.js and then checks the content.  I want to force spockets to compile (or render) the asset at the time of the test and not pull it from tmp/cache or any other place that it may already compiled.

How should I do this?  I don't see anything obvious in the sprockets code that says "ignore the cache".

Thank you in advance,
Perry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe setting a `null_store` as the cache backend is better than clearing the `tmp` folder everytime. try something like this on your test setup (after the application has been initialized):

```
Rails.application.assets.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:null_store)
```

Comment: Excellent!  Let me try that and I'll get back to you.  I wonder if I can put that in the environments/test.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
before(:each) do
  (Rails.root + "tmp/cache").rmtree
end
```

Following the suggestion my code is now this:

```
before(:each) do
  @original_cache = Rails.application.assets.cache
  Rails.application.assets.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:null_store)
end

after(:each) do
  Rails.application.assets.cache = @original_cache
end
```